# How to dispay elements properly

Tags: html, css

I've messed with my css/html code and now all the elements inside a div are placed in 1 line instead being shown just as normal `<p>contents</p>` tags each with a new line. A working example is here https://abereznyak.ru/projects/bot/php/index.php

Css and html.

```css
.card {
  /*    width: 320px;*/
  /*    height: 75px;*/
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.front,
.back {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*    width: 100%;*/
  /*    height: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.back {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.places {
  color: red;
}

.discount {
  color: green;
}

.timestamp {
  color: blue;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--main contents of the page in blocks form for each item-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php $k=1 ?>
    <?php foreach($requests as $request) : ?>
    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-12" id="content<?php echo $k ?>">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <p class="telegram_id">
            integer id
          </p>
          <p class="restaurant_name">

          </p>
          <p class="places">
            place count
          </p>
          <p class="discount">
            dicount
          </p>
          <p class="timestamp">
            time updated at
          </p>
          <button type="button">Wanna order</button>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          random contents
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php $k+=1 ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<!--main contents end is here-->
<!--jquery-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pr3w1k8x/

Thanks!

Comment: you are using display:flex, remove it or change the direction to column

Comment: Please show your code here, not only on an external site.

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks! How can I now make .tem class exacly as high as .front class?

Answer (score 1):

> In the CSS of class `.back` you are using `display:flex`  you should
>   remove that then you can get your answer each with a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `display:flex` from you `.front` class